# Java 2D rendering depth ideas

Tags: java, optimization, awt, 2d, java-2d

I'm writing a 2D isometric game engine in Java for fun and practice, and I've come to the point where I'm trying to figure out the most optimal way to render sprites in the correct order to simulate depth.  I haven't read much on the subject, but I always like to try coming up with my own solution before I use someone else's.  So, which of the two following solutions is more optimal and why?  And if I'm too far off, then what is the actual most optimal way to render sprites in the right order? Note - my game is free-moving like for example a 2D Zelda as opposed to the grid style in Pokemon Red.

1. I could use a linked list of the Entity objects stored in the order of their depth. Then whenever the each entity moves, compare its current Y position to the previous node and to the next node, and swap positions if necessary. Then, repeat that process until it's no longer necessary.  (I'm not sure how Java's linked lists work, but I could make a custom list if need be)
2. Just have an Entity array with a length equal to the height of the screen in pixels. Then when each entity moves, just change its position in the array to the position equal to its Y position on the screen (or the nearest available spot if that spot is taken).

Answer (score 1):

Note that by using an `AffineTransform` we can achieve pixel values (with dithering) to the accuracy of **`double`**. For smoothest results I would not settle on any technique that did not use pixel values in double.

> I just read up on`AffineTransform` and it looks incredibly useful; I'll probably start using it soon. However, I don't understand how that is applicable here.

I suspect it is relevant in ruling out a fixed size array, as seen in point 2.

Assuming the frames belong to a 'depth' (e.g. 1 pixel translation 'up' corresponds to a layer that is 1 level further away in distance), it is easy to keep a fixed **`integer`** size in relation to the number of pixels of height/potential depth in the final scene, but almost impossible to do it with a standard (fixed size) array of **`double`**.

As to point 1, you might sort the `List` of graphical elements using a `Comparator` that sorts by the `double` values of depth.  Then it is a simple matter of painting them in the order of the list.

Comment: Oh I understand.  When you said pixel values I thought you meant the color in the pixel.  Now I see how it applies here, and in this case I will go with the List option instead of the fixed array

Comment: *"Oh I understand."*  To be honest, when I read the answer back to myself just a few moments ago, I realized there were vital missing parts that have now been added in an edit.  In any case, you did come to the same basic understanding on your own.  :)